# Nginx Basic Auth On Codeigniter Routes returns 404 Error

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

I'm trying to protect DOMAIN.com/admin, the folder admin doesn't exist its just a route

I have a Codeigniter Controller called Admin.php

and the route for it as follows:

routes.php

```
$route['admin']                         = 'index_admin';
```

I'm trying to do Basic Auth, with Nginx

```
    location /admin {
    auth_basic         "Administrator’s Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

The authentication box is working, however I get 404 error after that.

Comment: did you perform Valet link operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed
added this to the location

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```